Mapping class group of non-orientable three manifold
I do not work in topology, but for some reason we need to know the mapping class group of certain non-orientable 3 manifolds. We found answers online for a lot of orientable manifolds. But we still don't know the answer for non-orientable ones, epscially of interest to us, $K \times S^1$ where $K$ is the Klein bottle. I suppose it should be something finite say $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ or $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$? Thanks.
Edit: Maybe it helps to mention that this space is also a circle bundle over the torus. There might be other ways, but I drew a solid cube with its 6 sides glued to see it.

It is actually infinite.

Hi. Is there a reference? Thanks

Lens spaces are orientable…

Sorry, my mistake

I suppose the main way to approach this problem is to consider all the possible Seifert fiberings of your manifold up to isotopy.  Diffeomorphisms send seifert fiberings to seifert fiberings, so you need to decide if they can be permuted, and how, then what is the fiber-preserving mapping class group.  As Moishe states, this group won't be finite as there's an epi-morphism to $\mathbb Z$.  That's the standard approach to these kinds of mapping class group questions.

Maybe it helps to mention that this space is also a circle bundle over the torus. There might be other ways, but I drew a solid cube with its 6 sides glued to see it.
